# What does /*!xxxxxx statement */ generated by mysqldump mean?

Tags: mysql

I was always curious about what these comment enclosed preprocessor-like statements that mysqldump generates for me mean. Here's an example:

```
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE abc DISABLE KEYS */;
```

The general pattern seems to be

```
/*![some numeric code] [some statement] */;
```

Please point to proper documentation if exists. Otherwise explain. :)

Comment: http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/sql-syntax-with-c-style-comments-in-mysqldump/

Answer (score 56, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comments.html

Comments of the form `/*! stuff */` are treated as comments by other RDBMSs, but MySQL will read what's inside the comment and execute it as SQL. You can use this to take advantage of MySQL-specific features even using code that might be run against other RDBMSs. For example you could use `/*! ENGINE=INNODB */` in a `CREATE TABLE` query.

The numbers are optional and if you use them then MySQL will ignore them if its version number is less than the number (with dots inserted in the appropriate places).