# titles of all wikipedia articles without redirect

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia, mediawiki-api

I am trying to get a list of all wikipedia title without redirects.

They say that they have about 6,410k articles. I tried to get a list though https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/ and the file enwiki-latest-all-titles-in-ns0.gz. But this has more than 16 million. So it includes titles with redirects

As suggested by an answer, I tried using quarry. I ran this simple query from the database enwiki_p:

```
select page_title from page where page_is_redirect = 0;
```

Now, the challenge with this is all titles which have more than one word are automatically considered redirects because this database removes all spaces in page title (see sample of database)

[image]

How do I know which page is an actual redirect or just considered on due to spaces being removed.

Answer (score 1):

There are other ways to do this. Being a contributor to wikimedia projects, you'll be able to run SQL queries in a site called [Quarry](https://quarry.wmcloud.org/). I'm not sure whether it can output large result set. But with SQL access you can really filter out redirects.

**UPDATE:**
As for [AccessibleComputing](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=AccessibleComputing&redirect=no), it's really a redirect, as you can visit the link which prevents actual redirecting.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer (you're just providing a reference link).

Comment: hey Alexander! thanks for the suggestion! I tried using quarry but ran into a challenge. have updated my question with details, could you please have a look

Answer (score 0):

Quarry was taking too long for me, I'm not sure if it would ever finish and if the results would be downloadable.

I managed to do it instead by downloading the dump [`enwiki-latest-page.sql`](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/enwiki-latest-page.sql.gz), which can be found from the dump listing at: https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/ , importing it into MariaDB locally, and then running a simple query on it:

```
sudo mariadb enwiki -B -N -e 'select page_title from page where page_namespace = 0 and page_is_redirect = 0 order by page_title' > titles.txt
```

It took about half an hour, but it got the job done.

I have provided further details at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77248954/895245